# Does riven ult do extra damage to low health baron?

Tags: league-of-legends

The damage is increased by 2.67% for every 1% of an enemy's missing health, capping at 200% bonus damage (300% total damage) against enemies with 75% or more missing health.

Does this work on baron?

Comment: why shouldnt it?

Comment: Yes it does, the tooltip says "enemy" which means any non-allies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does.

Windslash MAXIMUM PHYSICAL DAMAGE: 240 / 360 / 480 (+ 180% bonus AD)

[source](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Riven#Wind_Slash)